# How to logon to an Outlook mailbox?

Tags: c#, vbscript, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

I am trying to login to a mailbox using the following code, but it logs in to my local outlook mailbox instead of the one specified in the code in `oNS.Logon("account", "password", false, false)` line. Do I need to use `Redemption.RDOSession` for the same ? If so, how to use it in C#?

```
oApp = new Outlook.Application();
oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
oNS.Logon("account", "password", false, false);        

var EntryID = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).EntryID;
var StoreID = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).StoreID;

var folderID = oNS.GetFolderFromID(EntryID, StoreID);
```

When I use `RDSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox`, the error I am getting is as follows:

GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(collabera.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(collaberainc.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Error in WinHttpSendRequest(autodiscover.collaberainc.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT
HTTP error 401 from https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
Server response:

GetAutodiscoverUrlFromDns error: DNS lookup error using 172.17.18.50:DNS Server Reports Query Name Error
DNS lookup error using 172.30.30.53:DNS Server Reports Query Name Error
DNS lookup error using 172.30.30.11:DNS Server Reports Query Name Error
Expected HTTP_STATUS_REDIRECT, received 403
Could not retrieve any autodiscover URLs from DNS lookup

Answer (score 2):

`Namespace.Logon` in OOM takes the name of an existing profile (as shown in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles), *not* the name of a mailbox.

Since you tagged your question "Outlook-Redemption", I assume you are looking for a Redemption solution. In that case, use `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` - it indeed takes an SMTP address of an Exchange mailbox, configures a temporary profile, logs in, and deletes the profile.

Comment: I am trying to use  `Redemption.RDOSession`. I am still not able to find out how to use it. Can you tell me how to use it in C# to logon to a particular email profile ?

Comment: I figured how to add `Redemption` library to my C# code? I had to use http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm for downloading and adding the reference. Thanks for help. How to proceed further to logon to a specific profile in C# ?

Comment: RDOSession.Logon (just like Namespace.Logon) takes the name of the existing profile. If you pass an empty string, it will use the default profile.

Comment: I got busy with somwething else. That's why I am replying late. I tried RDOSession.Logon. It works fine. But now how to get sender's email using Redemption library ?

Comment: Also `RDOSession.Logon` works for local mailbox on my machine. `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` gives me ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

Comment: By "ender's email", do you mean the address of the current user? Use RDOsession.CurrentUser for that.

Comment: How are you calling LogonHostedExchangeMailbox?

Comment: By Sender's email, I mean From of Outlook mailbox. I am using LogonHostedExchangeMailbox as in `RDSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox("kanu.priya@xyz.com", "kanu.priya", "password")`.

Comment: Then RDOSession.CurrentUser is what you want. But you already know the email address since you pass it to LogonHostedExchangeMailbox

Comment: @Dimtry Streblechenko: If you are still there, the error I am getting is "There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address", for `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox`.

Comment: Can you post the full error? Redemption concatenates the errors from all potential autodiscover XML locations, and "There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address" is just one of them.

Comment: You are getting a 401 error, whcih means the credentials are wrong.

Comment: When I use different SMTP address in `RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` method, 401 error goes away, but autodiscover error remains. Do I need to add to add Autodiscover DNS record or something ?